# Why are the Ember component(s) for my notifications not being read/rendered?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've been stumped on this issue all day and have exhausted all possible reasons I can think of. The problem is that my handlebar to display a notification if the user has one is not displaying.

As it is early on, I'm just testing it out by when I click 'Sign in' button, it sends a notification to the user (me in this case) just so I can see it working.

To put it simply...it doesn't work. I've attached an image showing the final result on a webpage, and it seems to comment out the handlebar line, and ignore it. And I've not a clue why.

I know the data is being read, as the other classes/componenets (the .js files, and other files) are able to return the data in the console. My 'main-header' components and 'main-footer' components renders/reads fine across all pages.

I'm also using a near-enough exact copy of another website's code that uses this. And it works perfectly. Originally I made some changes but earlier I copy-pasted everything I thought relevant, and it still didn't work.

Here is the HTML for the **index.hbs** (the homepage/page shown in the screenshot)

```
<div>

    {{main-header}}
    {{notification-list notifications=application.currentNotifications closeNotification='closeNotification'}}z

</div>

<!--Navbar - Home, About and Contact. Fixed position follows user down page-->
<header id="header" role="banner">
  <!-- Navigation -->
</header>

<!--Main Body-->
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-center" type="submit" {{action 'login'}}>
    Sign In
    &nbsp;
  </button>


  <!--Footer containing copyright, logos and social media-->
{{main-footer}}
</div>
```

The **Homepage's .js** file;

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {

    }
});

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'index'
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({

    needs: ['application'],
    currentNotifications: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.application.currentNotifications"),

    actions: {
        login: function() {
            console.log(this.currentNotifications);
            this.send( 'pushNotification', 'Message Sent', false );
        }
    }
});
```

The **notification-list.hbs** file (Btw, the original was made using '{{#each x in y}}' and I had to change that due to deprecation, but ultimately it should work the same I believe;

```
 <div class="container notify">
  <div class="row">
      {{#each notifications as notification}}
          {{#if notification.error}}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"
                  {{action 'closeAlert' notification}}>
                ×
              </button>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span> <strong>{{notification.title}}</strong>
              <hr class="message-inner-separator">
                {{#each notification.message as message}}
                  <p>
                    <b>{{message.field}}</b>{{#if message.value}}: {{message.value}}{{/if}}
                  </p>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
          {{else}}
            <div class="alert alert-info">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"
                  {{action 'closeAlert' notification}}>
                ×
              </button>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> <strong>{{notification.title}}</strong>
              <hr class="message-inner-separator">
              <p>{{format-text notification.message}}</p>
            </div>
          {{/if}}
      {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

And the associated **notificationlist's .js** file;

```
App.NotificationListComponent = Ember.Component.extend( {
    notifications: [],

    lastLength: 0,

    didInsertElement: function(){
        if(this.notifications != null){
            this.notifications.forEach(function(notification){
                Ember.run.later( this, function () {
                    if ( this.notifications.indexOf( notification ) >= 0 ) {
                        this.send( 'closeAlert', notification );
                    }
                }, 3000 );
            }, this)
        }
    },

    ////DO NOT REFERENCE IN HANDLEBARS
    timeout: function() {
        var lastLength = this.get( 'lastLength' );
        var notifications = this.get( 'notifications' );

        //check it was an added notification, not a destroyed one
        if ( notifications.length >= lastLength ) {
            var index = notifications.length - 1;

            if ( index >= 0 ) {
                var notification = notifications[ index ];
                Ember.run.later( this, function () {
                    if ( notifications.indexOf( notification ) >= 0 ) {
                        this.send( 'closeAlert', notification );
                    }
                }, 3000 );
            }
        }
        //update last length
        this.set('lastLength', notifications.length);
    }.observes('notifications.length'),

    actions: {
        closeAlert: function( notification ){
            this.sendAction('closeNotification', notification);
        }
    }

});
```

Finally the **app.js** file. I've left some parts off that I don't think is relevant (such as the Adapter and store etc) if its needed lemme know though, but its pretty much the standard/default ones;

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

    currentNotifications: [],

    notification: Ember.Object.extend( {
        title: null,
        message: null,
        error: false
    } ),

    //Don't Call Directly, Use Route.Send to activate
    pushNotification: function( message, error ) {
        var currentNotifications = this.get( 'currentNotifications' );
        var notification = new this.notification;
        var test = error ? 'Failure' : 'Success';

        notification.setProperties( {
            title: test,
            message: message,
            error: error
        } );

        //Remove old message
        if(currentNotifications.length >= 4) {
            this.send('closeNotification', currentNotifications[0]);
        }

        currentNotifications.pushObject( notification );
    },

    closeNotification: function( notification ){
        var currentNotifications = this.get( 'currentNotifications' );
        var index = currentNotifications.indexOf(notification);
        //remove notification
        currentNotifications.removeAt(index);
    },

    updateCurrentPath: function() {
        App.set('currentPath', this.get('currentPath'));
    }.observes('currentPath')
});
```

The image showing the result of the above code. The highlighted line () is the line where the notification-list component is supposed to be

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If this is all of your code (unmodified), it seems like you're just giving it a bad value. In the template, you pass the notifications like this:

```
notifications=index.currentNotifications
```

Again, assuming that this is all of your code, I can't see where a variable named `index` would come from. You should probably be using `controller.currentNotifications`.

Comment: Oops my bad, again I was messing around with everything I could think. That being one of the things I messed around with (and evidently forgot to put right). Its actually meant to be 'application.currentNotifications' which also doesn't work (and was the original). I'll correct that now hehe

Comment: The same point is valid for `application.currentNotifications`. There is no property named `application` in scope. Have you tried `controller.currentNotifications`?

Comment: I hadn't but I just did. It doesn't work, instead gulp moans about deprecation of controller or any path based on it :(

Comment: What version of Ember are you using? Also, I don't know what linting process you have in Gulp, but I assure you that the `controller` variable exists in any controller template. My suggestions would be to put a `{{debugger}}` statement in your template and poke around in the context. As of right now, my best guess is that your component just isn't getting the data it needs. (Which would be pretty easy to test. Just throw some nonsense text after your `<div class="row">` tag.)

Comment: I think I'm using v1.13. I think I tried debugger before, it did nothing, unless by template you are referring to the index.hbs (or a js file?) I put the debugger into the 'notification-list.hbs' at the start (within the <div class="row"> ) and it didn't do anything, unless I used it wrongly haha, which is very possible

Comment: Ok, I ran the debugger (turns out I originally put the debugger in the componenet's hbs (notification-list.hbs) and it didn't run - it appears that the program isn't even going into the file or something. But I ran it a bit to see what was happening, and I couldn't really tell what I was looking for haha. With 80,000 lines of code, it was jumping all over the place haha :/

Comment: If your debugger isn't stopping after you put a `{{debugger}}` statement in your template, it's because your template isn't being used. Make sure that whatever build system you're using is actually resolving your template correctly. (I'd suggest Ember CLI if that's possible.)

Comment: It turns out it was a naming issue, I named the file notitication-list.hbs instead of notification-list.hbs haha. Thanks for your help though